# Why does the armature voltage of a synchronous machine (generator) decreases with a increase of active power

Tags: simulation, electric-machine, synchronous

I am running a simulated synchronous machine in matlab and strugling to understand its behaviour. The machine is running as a generator, keeping everything else at nominal value if I increase the load power connected to the machine from 1% to 20% of nominal power I see a small drop in the armature voltage and I cant understand this behaviour.

Comment: due to armature resistance

Answer (score 0):

This result is due to armature resistance.